# How to run a file in vbscript within the code given below?

Tags: file, date, vbscript, copy

Here's the code that I found which matches my criteria. The code below is used to copy file from source path to target path.

Conditions implied:
Only if the file doesn't exist on the target path or if the file exists but its older then the source path and the target file is overwritten.

How do I run a target file within this code so that the target file runs only when the file is being overwritten or the target file is freshly copied?

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell
Dim fso
Dim USERPROFILE
Dim srcPath
Dim tgtPath
On Error Resume Next

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
'USERPROFILE = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

srcPath = "C:\test.exe"
tgtPath = "D:\"

If Not fso.FileExists(tgtPath) Then
fso.CopyFile srcPath, tgtPath, True
ElseIf fso.FileExists(srcPath) Then
ReplaceIfNewer srcPath, tgtPath
End If

Sub ReplaceIfNewer(strSourceFile, strTargetFile)
Const OVERWRITE_EXISTING = True

Dim objFso
Dim objTargetFile
Dim dtmTargetDate
Dim objSourceFile
Dim dtmSourceDate

Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTargetFile = objFso.GetFile(strTargetFile)
dtmTargetDate = objTargetFile.DateLastModified
Set objSourceFile = objFso.GetFile(strSourceFile)
dtmSourceDate = objSourceFile.DateLastModified
If (dtmTargetDate < dtmSourceDate) Then
objFso.CopyFile objSourceFile.Path, objTargetFile.Path,OVERWRITE_EXISTING
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a reworded and working vesion of your script

```
option explicit 

dim WshShell, fso, srcPath, tgtPath , file, objFileSrc, objFileTgt
const OVERWRITE = true

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

file = "test.exe"
srcPath = "c:\" 
tgtPath = "e:\" 

if fso.FileExists(srcPath & file) then
  if not fso.FileExists(tgtPath & file) then
    'target doesn't exist, just copy
    fso.CopyFile srcPath & file, tgtPath
    wscript.echo srcPath & file & " copied to " & tgtPath & file
  else
    Set objFileSrc = fso.getFile(srcPath & file)
    Set objFileTgt = fso.getFile(tgtPath & file)
    'target exists, compare dates
    if objFileSrc.DateLastModified > objFileTgt.DateLastModified then
      fso.CopyFile srcPath & file, tgtPath, OVERWRITE
      wscript.echo srcPath & file & " copied over " & tgtPath & file
    else
      wscript.echo srcPath & file & " not newer then " & tgtPath & file
    end if
  end if
else
  wscript.echo srcPath & file & " does not exist"
end if
set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the script peter. I was wondering how do you run the Targetfile after it is being copied. I tried using WshShell.Run tgtpath & file but that didn't work for me as the file is being copied from the network to the target machine.